# Meaning of modules of finite dimension

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field, let $R=k^{m}$ where $m \geq 1$ and let $M$ be a $R$-bimodule. What shall we understand by a "basis" of $M$? or "finite dimensional over $R$"?

Comment: Where did you see these terms used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since in this case $R$ is commutative, it satisfies the invariant basis number property, so that it is meaningful to speak of the *rank* of $M$. This is probably what is meant by the "dimension" of $M$ over $R$, i.e., the number $n$ such that $M \cong R^n$. In this case a *basis* of $M$ means a set of $n$ linearly independent elements that generate $M$.